Defining clinical follow-up: Fixed Period vs. Maximum Duration
We are retrospectively analyzing data of around 1100 patients operated between 2017 and 2023. We analyzed follow-up documentation until 2024. This means that patients operated at a later date will naturally have a shorter follow-up.
Should we set a uniform follow-up period and only analyze complications that occurred within 12 months after surgery for each patient and disregard any complication that occurred after? Or should we not discard any complications that we know of even though follow-up periods may differ between patients?
We are not planning a survival analysis.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You are effectively performing "survival analysis," but your event is complication rather than death. Tools for survival analysis can be used for any defined type of event if you want to model the time to event. Standard survival analysis would allow you to use all data while taking into account the "right censoring" of later patients' times to complication.
It sometimes makes sense, however, to limit evaluation of surgical complications to a restricted time period during which a complication might reasonably be expected to have been due to the surgery rather than some other cause. Then you could have a simple binomial model of whether there was a complication within, say, 12 months of surgery. That's a matter to be determined by your understanding of the subject matter rather than statistical analysis per se.
You might combine the two approaches by fitting a full "survival" model with complication as the event, but focusing on survival estimates at 12 months. That would provide information about the time to the complication that a binomial model would not.
An additional reason to consider a survival model: if there are deaths in your data, then death and complication might be considered competing risks that should be modeled together. See the R survival package, especially its vignette on competing risks.

Thank you for your answer. If I understand correctly, you are saying that wether a set period of follow-up for each patient or unlimited follow-ups of varying lengths are appropriate is more a choice to be made based on subject knowledge than statistics?

@Philipp that's essentially correct. It's mostly a question of whether you care about events that occur after your set follow-up period. If you don't, then you can censor administratively at a set time after surgery. If you do, then you should include all data. Even if you use a set follow-up period, I would recommend that you use survival analysis methods. That way you include individuals who haven't yet reached that follow-up time and you can evaluate competing risks (like death).

It depends on what you are trying to prove. If you are trying to test that complication rates have decreased over the years (or at a minimnum test if they have changed over time), then you need to compare over similar follow-up periods. E.g. you can compare each year of data for complications at 12 months. But you can also compare 2017 to 2018 at 48 months, and 2017, 2018 and 2019 at 36 months, etc. And the comparision will be based on a binomial test, using contingency matrices (7x2 for complications at 12 months, 2x2 for complications at 48 months, etc.). Since you say "we are not planning a survival analysis", that would be the most direct answer to your question.
If instead you assume that the complication rate/behavior is pretty constant over the 7 years, then you can try modelling that complication/survival rate, and then you can combine all the survival data you have, regardless of the follow-up period (because you are not comparing 2 (or more) distributions, but instead are modeling a single distribution). This is basically a reliability/survival analysis (which you say you are not interested in).
Last, you could try to model the survival/reliability for each year. For 2017 you would have more/better data than for 2023, so your model will be better, but the 2023 model will not be "wrong" or even not useful. And from that you could infer that complication rates/behaviors changed (or not) over time.
So, if you could clarify the question(s) you are trying to answer, that may help us provide more focused answers.

Thank you very much for your detailed answer. The reason we opted against a survival analysis is that time to complication does not have much clinical relevance in our case. We are comparing different surgical techniques and resulting complications which affect patients in the same way, regardless of when they occur.
Assuming a simple model of True / False is appropriate in our situation, would it  simply be a question of subject matter / expert knowledge to set a specific follow-up period vs. including all observed complications?

Let's assume a (very) simple model for the complications, with a probability $\lambda$ of complication per unit of time (month, year, ...)., with $\lambda$ constant over the 7 years in your study. It should be clear that the surgeries performed in 2017 would have a much higher chance of experiencing complications than those from 2023. And not because the techniques/surgeons were poorer in 2017... So if you are trying to compare different techniques used in different years, and want to use a simple binomial true/false model, you need to use a uniform follow-up period. ...cont

...cont. But if you try to model the $\lambda$ parameter for each year/surgical technique, and then compare these rates, you will be doing a survical analysis, but then you could use all the data (albeit that your model will be better for 2017 than for 2023).

I understand, thank you for the clarification. May I just add that the probability of complication decreases substantially with time. So while a late complication is as bad as an early complication, it is much less likely.

Given the two options (binomial and survival), which one would you recommend in my case?
One argument in favor of the binomial model may be that due to the retrospective nature of the study we rely on follow-up documentation. This means that while a complication may be documented after 6 months, it may have already occurred after 3 months. I think this would have less of an effect in the binomial model, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

The binomial analysis is simple, quick, but coarse, and requires uniform follow-up period. The survival analysis is more complex, but gives you much finer grain details on the "failure mode" (aka complications) of the various surgical techniques. Honestly, I would do both; they are not conflicting ways to analyze.
